# Balancing parentheses (),{},[] routine

Tags: c#, balanced-delimiters

I have written a simple routine to check if the number of parentheses balances, so `[{}]` would return true since all parentheses which are opened are closed in the correct order. `[)({}]` would return false since you cant start with a closing parentheses.

Is anyone able to improve the routine - (efficiency, readability) since I think it works for most cases ?

Here is the code.

```
public class Compiler
    {
        private Stack<char> Stack { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        private char[] Parentheses { get; set; }

        public Compiler()
        {
            Text = "";

            //These are what I classify as parentheses (opening & closing)
            Parentheses = new char[] { '{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']' };

            Stack = new Stack<char>();
        }

        private bool IsParentheses(char letter)
        {
            if (Parentheses.Contains(letter))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public bool IsParenthesesBalanced()
        {
            foreach (char letter in Text)
            {
                if (IsParentheses(letter))
                {
                    if (IsOpeningParentheses(letter))
                    {
                        //Add to stack
                        Stack.Push(letter);
                    }
                    else if (Stack.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // Stack contains opening parentheses so {,(,[
                        // We pop elements when we find closing parenthese.
                        char top = Stack.Peek();

                        if (!IsCorrentClosingParenthese(top, letter))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        Stack.Pop();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Stack should we should a opening parenthese otherwise if we
                        // Pop when stack is empty it will throw an error.

                        // This handles when user provide first letter as a closing parenthese 
                        // rather then opening so ]()[
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Stack.Count == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool IsOpeningParentheses(char parenthese)
        {
            int index = Array.IndexOf(Parentheses, parenthese);

            // All opening parenthese are even position in array - 
            // '{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']'
            //  0    1    2    3    4    5

            if (index % 2 == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool IsCorrentClosingParenthese(char openingParenthese, char closingParenthese)
        {
            // All matching parenthese it start with opening and next is closing - 
            // '{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']'
            //  0    1    2    3    4    5
            // We can check if the next openingIndex + 1 position is equal to closingParenthese
            // In short just check next element.

            int openingIndex = Array.IndexOf(Parentheses, openingParenthese);

            if (Parentheses[openingIndex + 1] == closingParenthese)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here I am using the class

```
var compiler = new Compiler();
            compiler.Text = @"using System;
                            namespace HelloWorldApplication
                            {
                               class HelloWorld
                               {
                                  static void Main(string[] args)
                                  {
                                     /* my first program in C# */
                                     Console.WriteLine(Hello World);
                                     Console.ReadKey();
                                  }
                                }
                             }";

            compiler.IsParenthesesBalanced();
```

Comment: You are not interested in quoted parentheses, are you?

Comment: No. I dont need to worry about quoted parentheses. Its going to be a code checker.

Comment: ...and what if I write `"1) Hallo World."`? I think you don't know yet that you (need to) care about quotes :-)

Comment: btw this `Console.WriteLine(Hello World);` is not valid C#.

Comment: Your right. A string could contain be "1) Hallo World" and the program will think its syntax so it needs a closing parentheses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can make a few improvements that will make this class not only more useful but also easier to understand.

---

I'd start with naming the class according to its job, which is `ParenthesesValidator`. Then the main method becomes `ValidateParenthesesBalanced`. The next step is to throw away the constructor and the `Text` property. It doesn't have to be the state of the class. You can perfectly pass it to the validating method. The same with the `Stack`. What can be local to a method should be local. This way you can make less mistakes by overwriting the data and contribute to the thread-safety of the validation.

Then let's take care of the definition of the parentheses that currently is an array:

> ```
> Parentheses = new char[] { '{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']' };
> ```

This requries some computations to find the matchin paretheses but there is another way. With the new tuples you can define a few helper variables that will allow you to greatly simplify the logic.

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<(char Opening, char Closing)> Parentheses = new (char, char)[] { ('{', '}'), ('(', ')'), ('[', ']') };
private static readonly ISet<char> OpeningParentheses = new HashSet<char>(Parentheses.Select(p => p.Opening));
private static readonly ISet<char> ClosingParentheses = new HashSet<char>(Parentheses.Select(p => p.Closing));
private static readonly ISet<char> AllParentheses = new HashSet<char>(OpeningParentheses.Concat(ClosingParentheses));
private static readonly IDictionary<char, char> ParenthesesMap = Parentheses.ToDictionary(p => p.Opening, p => p.Closing);
```

You first create a collection of all `Parentheses` naming them as  `Opening` and `Closing.` You use it to build the other helper collections. Using hash-sets is usually faster then scanning arrays because it is an O(1) operation unlike the O(n) with an array. Lastly you create a dictionary that will map an opening paretheses to a closing one so you don't have to compute anything.

With this optimization your code becomes two one-liners:

```
private bool IsParentheses(char letter)
{
     return AllParentheses.Contains(letter);    
}

private bool IsCorrectClosingParenthese(char openingParenthese, char closingParenthese) 
{
    return ParenthesesMap[openingParenthese] == closingParenthese;
}
```

---

You can also remove this condition

> ```
> if (IsParentheses(letter))
> ```

by plugging this method into a `Where` *behind* the `text`

```
foreach (char letter in text.Where(IsParentheses))
```

---

After putting everything together your code would look like this:

```
public class ParenthesesValidator
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<(char Opening, char Closing)> Parentheses = new (char, char)[] { ('{', '}'), ('(', ')'), ('[', ']') };
    private static readonly ISet<char> OpeningParentheses = new HashSet<char>(Parentheses.Select(p => p.Opening));
    private static readonly ISet<char> ClosingParentheses = new HashSet<char>(Parentheses.Select(p => p.Closing));
    private static readonly ISet<char> AllParentheses = new HashSet<char>(OpeningParentheses.Concat(ClosingParentheses));
    private static readonly IDictionary<char, char> ParenthesesMap = Parentheses.ToDictionary(p => p.Opening, p => p.Closing);

    public bool ValidateParenthesesBalanced(string text)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<char>();

        foreach (char letter in text.Where(IsParentheses))      
        {
            if (OpeningParentheses.Contains(letter))
            {
                stack.Push(letter);
            }
            else if (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                // Stack contains opening parentheses so {,(,[
                // We pop elements when we find closing parenthese.
                var top = stack.Peek();

                if (!IsCorrectClosingParenthese(top, letter))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                stack.Pop();
            }
            else
            {
                // Stack should we should a opening parenthese otherwise if we
                // Pop when stack is empty it will throw an error.

                // This handles when user provide first letter as a closing parenthese 
                // rather then opening so ]()[
                return false;
            }
        }

        return stack.Count == 0;
    }

    private bool IsParentheses(char letter)
    {
         return AllParentheses.Contains(letter);    
    }

    private bool IsCorrectClosingParenthese(char openingParenthese, char closingParenthese) 
    {
        return ParenthesesMap[openingParenthese] == closingParenthese;
    }
}
```

---

Additionally you can easily fix the quoted text and skip it by adding a small helper method to the class:

```
private static IEnumerable<char> SkipQuoted(IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    var escapeMode = false;
    foreach (var c in chars)
    {
        if (c == '"' && !escapeMode)
        {
            escapeMode = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (escapeMode)
        {
            if (c == '"')
            {
                escapeMode = false;
            }
            continue;
        }

        yield return c;
    }
}
```

You then pass the `text` first to this method before grabbing the paretheses:

```
foreach (char letter in SkipQuoted(text).Where(IsParentheses))
```

Comment: Looks like the `foreach` loop in the `SkipQuoted` method could be simplified to `foreach (var c in chars) { if (c == '"') { escapeMode = !escapeMode; continue; } yield return c; }`.  However, both methods only handle the case of a simple string. A string with an escaped quotation mark (`"\""`) and a string using string interpolation (`$"This is an interpolated {typeof(string).Name}."`) would both fail.

Comment: @Jaquez oh, you're so right and on the other hand it's _just_ an example ;-)

Comment: Totally.  Just wanted to point it out so that someone didn't try to blindly use it somewhere.  Not that that EVER happens to code here. ;-)  The rest of the review is spot on and better than I would have come up with.  Definitely a +1 from me.

Answer (score 10):

This

> ```
> private Stack<char> Stack { get; set; }
> public string Text { get; set; }
> private char[] Parentheses { get; set; }
>
> public Compiler()
> {
>     Text = "";
>
>     //These are what I classify as parentheses (opening & closing)
>     Parentheses = new char[] { '{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']' };
>
>     Stack = new Stack<char>();
> }
> ```

can be rewritten as

```
private Stack<char> Stack { get; } = new Stack<char>();
public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
private char[] Parentheses { get; } = new char[] { '{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']' };
```

---

Code like this

> ```
> if (Parentheses.Contains(letter))
> {
>     return true;
> }
> return false;
> ```

can be simplified to

```
return Parentheses.Contains(letter);
```

---

These checks

> ```
> Stack.Count > 0
> Stack.Count == 0
> ```

can be changed to

```
Stack.Any()
!Stack.Any()
```